# Смысловая нагрузка внутренних классов в java

Tags: java

Если в случае c вложенными классами (nested) я могу понять зачем они нужны, то зачем нужны еще и внутренние классы (inner), какова их практическая роль ?

Comment: `inner`-класс имеет неявную ссылку на инстанс внешнего класса, соответственно ему доступно состояние внешнего класса.

Comment: nested тоже имеет,  для этого в нем нужно обьявить метод и прописать return имя_класса_обертки.this

Comment: `static nested` класс не имеет доступа к состоянию внешнего класса.

Comment: я про не статический класс который объявляется внутри метода